# How can I make EclipseLink not annotate @javax.annotation.processing.Generated on my static metamodels?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

It seems the EclipseLink put `@javax.annotation.processing.Generated` annotation on my static metamodels.

I suppressed that annotation, with my hibernate profile, using `-AaddGeneratedAnnotation=false` option.

How can I do that with EclipseLink?